# Es posible hacer que un campo acepte valores unicos pero a su vez permita el valor null en mongo?

Tags: mongodb, graphql, nestjs

estoy aprendiendo a usar mongo con nestjs y graphql y tengo un campo en una colección donde almaceno el ObjectId con el que hago referencia a otro archivo de otra colección. Lo que pasa es que quiero que ese campo sea opcional y que al mismo tiempo no acepte ObjectId repetidas. Es posible entonces que un campo de una colección acepte datos únicos pero a su vez permita almacenar datos null?

Comment: El tema es que null también va a tomar como repetido...

Comment: Creo que ya encontre como solucionarlo, es cuestion de agregar la propiedad sparse al indice y se supone que a la hora de usar dicho indice omitira aquellos que sean nulos y no viola la unicidad del campo pero no he terminado de probarlo.

Comment: Ok. No olvides responder a tu propia pregunta en caso de encontrar respuestas. Por cierto, haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, así podrás obtener tu primera [medalla](/help/badges).